# Feature selection method based on target variable in R

Tags: r, feature-selection, caret

I have dataset from 30 different features and a result variable. All the features have values like -1,0,1 and my result variable contains -1 and 1 , which 1 means record is healthy and -1 means disease.

I have read a lot in Caret vignette but sorry I couldn't find relevant code to my problem.

what is the best method for selecting features for such dataset in R?
How can I select best features based on my result variable in R?